# To handle the profiles

Tags: profile

For the specific profile ,I have given the **Object Permissions** for eg: **Account** Object-*Create,Edit* and *Read* in this Iam able to create a new account and edit that created account but iam not able to edit the **existing account**, so May I know what's the Reason

Comment: Check Owners role or is there any sharing rule ?

Comment: Hi Prathyusha,thanks for your prompt reply ,for this particular profile i dont have any sharing rule

Comment: What is the Org Wide defaults for your Account object?

Comment: I'd suggest completing the [Data Security](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security) module on Trailhead to get a better sense of all of the different factors that could play a role in record-level access.

Comment: Hi Mohith Shrivastava,thanks for your reply, Org Wide defaults for my Account object is **Public Read Only**

Comment: As OWD is public read only , you will not be able to edit record.when it is public read only-  All users can view records, but only the owner, and users above that role in the hierarchy, can edit them.